# visual studio - invalid std::string debugger output in Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging

[image]

There's nothing fancy going on in this program, but I get garbage output. Here are the header files I'm including, in case that's relevant.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

And I'm using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows XP.

Note that if I print the string to stdout, it prints "test" perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes the debugger will have trouble picking up proper values if you've compiled in Release mode.  The compiler might swap around operations or move values to registers, etc.

Comment: Is there a way to display actual values (e.g. for string) then, without printing it? Maybe using Watch window?

Comment: @PavelK no, the watch window uses the same mechanism to find the value. The only way is to switch to a debug build or drop down to assembler to see the optimized code.

Comment: This happens in debug builds too, and is very common, although there is very little information about this problem available.

Comment: @FlorianWinter not in my experience.